# Models not connecting as I think they should be

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, has-many, belongs-to

Why am I getting this error a _form's select within Bids?

```
=>  undefined method `request_for_proposal' for  
# <ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x002aaad671c9c8>
```

request_for_proposal **has_many** bids
bids **belongs_to**  request_for_proposal

```
====================================================
Inside views/bids/_form.html.erb

  <div class="field">  
    <%= bid.label :vendor_name %>  
    <%= bid.select :vendor_id, bid.request_for_proposal.vendors.collect { |rfpvi|  
        [rfpvi.friendly_name + "  :  " + rfpvi.rfp_number, rfpvi.id] } %>  
  </div>
```

In Bids I need to go through the RFP to get "invited_vendors" so that I can later limit or restrict the vendors that can actually submit a bid.

```
class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :cost, :request_for_proposal_id, :vendor_id

  belongs_to :request_for_proposal
  belongs_to :vendor
------------------------------------------------

mysql> desc bids;
+-------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                   | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                      | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| cost                    | decimal(10,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| request_for_proposal_id | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| vendor_id               | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| contact_id              | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at              | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at              | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  

================================================
class RequestForProposal < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible   :rfp_number, :name, :description, :title,
                    :contact_id, :business_owner_id

  has_many   :bids
  has_many   :rfp_vendors
  has_many   :vendors, :through => :rfp_vendors

  has_and_belongs_to_many   :business_owners, :class_name => :Contact,
                            :foreign_key => :business_owner_id
  has_and_belongs_to_many   :evaluators,      :class_name => :Contact,
                            :foreign_key => :evaluator_id
 ----------------------------------------------- 

mysql> desc request_for_proposals;
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| rfp_number                 | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| contact_id                 | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| vendor_id                  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name                       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description                | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| title                      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| bid_id                     | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| business_owner_id          | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| evaluator_id               | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at                 | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at                 | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

================================================
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :friendly_name

    has_many :rfp_vendors
    has_many :request_for_proposals, :through => :rfp_vendors
    has_many :bids
------------------------------------------------

mysql> desc vendors;
+-------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| friendly_name           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at              | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at              | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

================================================
================================================

mysql> desc bids_contacts;
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| bid_id     | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| contact_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> desc bids_vendors;
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| bid_id    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| vendor_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> desc rfp_vendors;
+-------------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                   | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                      | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| vendor_id               | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| request_for_proposal_id | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at              | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at              | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

????????????????????????????????????????????????????

After I get past this annoying inability to 'see' request_for_proposals,

I'm going to need to reach Vendors via the :through => :rfp_venders.

Will I have nuances to worry about to reach Vendors.friendly_name?

Answer (score 1):

From the irb error you've shown, it looks like you're calling `request_for_proposal` on the form builder instance, not the ActiveRecord instance itself.

If you have `form_for @my_instance do |f|`, then within the block the `f` is a form builder instance, not the same object as `@my_instance`; you should use `@my_instance` or `f.object` to get to the ActiveRecord instance.

Comment: Thanks bloopletech.  
I just changed it to:

    <div class="field">

      <%= bid.label :vendor_name %>

      <%= bid.select :vendor_id, @bid.request_for_proposal.vendors.collect { |rfpvi| [rfpvi.friendly_name + "  :  " + rfpvi.rfp_number, rfpvi.id] } %>

    </div>

However the error now is:

    undefined method `rfp_number' for #<Vendor:0x002aaae01b18d0>

Comment: EUREKA!  My error on what I was trying to display.  That's a relief that this nonsense problem is solved.  I'll remember that. ______ Now I just have to figure out in my Bids' form how to restrict the vendors selected for the bid based on the list that I now know I can get at! ______  Another challenge!  :) _____ Thanks!